# Table rows disappearing on going to the next page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, material-ui

I am new to react. I am using an addrow method to add the values to the table I created using {this.state.rows.map}. The table appears with the values of the input fields. However on pressing the continue button to go to the next page and then coming back from the page by pressing the back button, the row disappears. [image: Before going to the next page][image: After coming back from the page]

Here is the code:

```
<Grid item xs={10} direction="row" alignItems="center">
              <table
                className="table table-bordered table-hover"
                id="tab_logic"
              >
                <thead>
                  {this.state.rows.length > 0 ? (
                    <tr>
                      <th className="text-center"> # </th>
                      <th className="text-center"> KPI </th>
                      <th className="text-center"> UOM </th>
                      <th className="text-center"> Base </th>
                      <th className="text-center"> Target </th>
                      <th className="text-center"> Target Date </th>
                      <th className="text-center"> Delete Row </th>
                    </tr>
                  ) : null}
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {this.state.rows.map((item, idx) => (
                    <tr id="addr1" key={idx}>
                      <td>{idx + 1}</td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="Kpi_Before"
                          defaultValue={Kpi_Before}
                          onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                          className="form-control"
                          readOnly
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="UOM_Before"
                          defaultValue={UOM_Before}
                          onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                          className="form-control"
                          readOnly
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="Base_Before"
                          defaultValue={Base_Before}
                          onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                          className="form-control"
                          readOnly
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="Target_Before"
                          defaultValue={Target_Before}
                          onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                          className="form-control"
                          readOnly
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="dateTime"
                          defaultValue={dateTime}
                          onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                          className="form-control"
                          readOnly
                          size="38"
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
```

The code for changes and going back and forward is this:

```
continue = e => {
e.preventDefault();
      this.props.nextStep();
    }
  };

back = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.prevStep();
  };

handleChangeRows = idx => e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const rows = [...this.state.rows];

    rows[idx] = {
      [name]: value
    };

    this.setState({
      rows
    });
  };



handleAddRow = () => {const item = {
        Kpi_Before: [],
        UOM_Before: "",
        Base_Before: "",
        Target_Before: "",
        dateTime: "",
        rows:[]
      };
      this.setState({
        rows: [...this.state.rows, item]
      });
    }
  };




nextStep = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step + 1
    });
  };

  //Go back to previous step
  prevStep = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step - 1
    });
  };
```

How do I keep the rows from disappearing and keep it constant on moving back and forward?

Comment: It's not okay to use idx as keys since when you change the state (array) items change but indexes stay. You have to use some kind of ids that map to each item and stay the same when you change those within the state.

Comment: Hi thanks for the info can you give an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

Your state re-renders when you navigate between pages or refresh which means everything inside state is lost to combat this you can either:

1) Use redux to store changes and retrieve data from there.

2) Use Context API which is the same as redux but builtin to react.

3) Consume a REST API which means have some sort of backend to store the values and get them on component mount.

Comment: Is there an example that you can give. A short example would do.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93p3LxR9xfM this should explain everything you need to know about redux. Its very important part of react so learning it would benefit you in the future.